# Finding a linear relationship between functions?

Tags: linear-transformations, functional-equations

I guess, this might even be high-school level - but if it is, I definitely forgot how this operation is called, and all my online searches are fruitless, so I thought I'd ask here.

Here, I've constructed some functions:

[image: plot-of-functions]

Now, let's assume I know the analytical forms of $y_1(x)$, $y_2(x)$ and $y_3(x)$; and I have a recording of $y_4(x)$ in the domain shown on the plot, but I do not have its analytical form.

At this point, if I make the assumption, that $y_4(x)$ is a linear combination of $y_1(x)$, $y_2(x)$ and $y_3(x)$:

$$ y_4(x) = a + b\cdot y_1(x) + c\cdot y_2(x) + d\cdot y_3(x)$$

... is there a procedure, that would take in the data of all four functions ( $y_1(x)$, $y_2(x)$, $y_3(x)$ and $y_4(x)$) in a given domain of $x$, and allow me to calculate the linear coefficients $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ (at least one set of such values)? If so, what is this procedure/operation called?

Comment: Least squares approximation?

Comment: Thanks @UltimateApple - I had remembered least squares technique in its most simple form (for a single function of a single independent variable), which is why I did not consider it in my previous searches - so thanks a ton for mentioning it! It led me to [General linear model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_model) and [Multiple linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_linear_regression), which I think is applicable here.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with "a recording” of $y_4(x)$ in the domain of the plot? If you meant that you can find out the value of $y_4(x)$ for those values of $x$, then all you need to do it is choose four values for $x$, let's say $2$, $4$, $6$ and $8$, feed that values to the expression $y_4(x) = a + b\cdot y_1(x) + c\cdot y_2(x) + d\cdot y_3(x)$ to get four linear equations in $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ and solve that linear system of equations to find $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$.

Edit:

I you have the data points, then you can choose a pair $(u,v)$ from those thousands of points. Set $x=u$ in the expression to get $v = a+ b\cdot y_1(u) + c\cdot y_2(u) +d \cdot y_3(u)$, a linear equation in $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$. Do that four times to get a linear system of equations and solve that system. That would allow you to find the values of $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$. Then you'll have an analytic form of $y_4$

Comment: By "a recording" I mean I have a set of data points, without knowing the actual analytical form of the function that generated them; the "domain of the plot" would just mean that I have this set of points in the $x$ range of $[-10, 10]$. Note that there may be thousands of points in this range, and solving analytically as in your example of 4 points might be difficult. In that sense, I just realized that this is more of a statistics question; and I guess [Multiple linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_linear_regression) was the name of the operation I was looking for.